Unity new input system triggering shoot multiple times
I am new to unity and game making but i am following multiple tutorials and have gotten down the basics of the new input system as i am new i think i should hop on that. I got first person movement to work in my 3D game and i added a shoot action but for some reason it is triggering multiple times sometimes up to 10 times. I set up so i can see in the console when it is being triggered.
I have code for my input handler here:
[Header("Input Action Asset")]
[SerializeField] private InputActionAsset playerControls;

[Header("Action Map Name References")]
[SerializeField] private string actionMapName = "Gameplay";

private InputAction moveAction;
private InputAction lookAction;
private InputAction jumpAction;
private InputAction sprintAction;
private InputAction interactAction;
private InputAction shootAction;

public Vector2 MoveInput {  get; private set; }
public Vector2 LookInput { get; private set; }
public bool JumpTriggered { get; private set; }
public float SprintValue { get; private set; }
public bool InteractTriggered { get; private set; }
public bool ShootTriggered { get; private set; }

public static PlayerInputHandler instance { get; private set; }

private void Awake()
{
    if(instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    moveAction = playerControls.FindActionMap(actionMapName).FindAction("Move");
    lookAction = playerControls.FindActionMap(actionMapName).FindAction("Look");
    jumpAction = playerControls.FindActionMap(actionMapName).FindAction("Jump");
    sprintAction = playerControls.FindActionMap(actionMapName).FindAction("Sprint");
    interactAction = 
    playerControls.FindActionMap(actionMapName).FindAction("Interact");
    shootAction = playerControls.FindActionMap(actionMapName).FindAction("Shoot");
    RegisterInputActions();


}

private void RegisterInputActions()
{
    moveAction.performed += context => MoveInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    moveAction.canceled += context => MoveInput = Vector2.zero;

    lookAction.performed += context => LookInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    lookAction.canceled += context => LookInput = Vector2.zero;

    jumpAction.performed += context => JumpTriggered = true;
    jumpAction.canceled += context => JumpTriggered = false;

    sprintAction.performed += context => SprintValue = context.ReadValue<float>();
    sprintAction.canceled += context => SprintValue = 0f;

    interactAction.performed += context => InteractTriggered = true;
    interactAction.canceled += context => InteractTriggered = false;

    shootAction.performed += context => ShootTriggered = true;
    shootAction.canceled += context => ShootTriggered = false;



}

private void OnEnable()
{
    moveAction.Enable();
    lookAction.Enable();
    jumpAction.Enable();
    sprintAction.Enable();
    interactAction.Enable();
    shootAction.Enable();
}
private void OnDisable()
{
    moveAction.Disable();
    lookAction.Disable(); 
    jumpAction.Disable();
    sprintAction.Disable();
    interactAction.Disable();
    shootAction.Disable();
}

And this is the code that i have on the gun:
[SerializeField] private float damage = 10f;
[SerializeField] private float range = 100f;


private PlayerInputHandler inputHandler;
private Camera cam;


void Start()
{
    cam = Camera.main;
    inputHandler = PlayerInputHandler.instance;
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(inputHandler.ShootTriggered)
    {
        shoot();
    }
}

private void shoot()
{


    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        Debug.DrawRay(cam.transform.position, cam.transform.forward * range);
        Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
        if(target != null) 
        {
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
}

I have tried changing the the events from performed to started i have tried finding a solution but cant seem to have any success

sounds like   RegisterInputActions is being called more than once. such as when you die....

@BugFinder nothing like dying in the game yet i am fairly knew so i dont think thats getting called twice

add debug statements, check whats going on, but shoot looks like it would be triggered every frame...
